# auto.arima Not Minimizing AIC

Tags: r, time-series, arima, moving-average

I simulated a MA(3) process using:

```
set.seed(66)
w <- rnorm(100,0,3.6)
p1 <- 0.4; p2 <- -0.2; p3 <- 0.3;
ma3 <- w[1]
ma3[2] <- w[2] + p1*w[1] 
ma3[3] <- w[3] + p1*w[2] + p2*w[1]
for (t in 4:100) ma3[t] <- w[t] + p1*w[t-1] + p2*w[t-2] + p3*w[t-3]
```

Running auto.arima on the time series gives:

```
> auto.arima(ma3)                                   
Series: ma3 
ARIMA(0,0,1) with zero mean     

Coefficients:
         ma1
      0.3854
s.e.  0.1152

sigma^2 estimated as 14.41:  log likelihood=-275.39
AIC=554.77   AICc=554.89   BIC=559.98
```

However, fitting the series to a MA(3) model gives a lower AIC:

```
> arima(ma3, order=c(0,0,3))

Call:
arima(x = ma3, order = c(0, 0, 3))

Coefficients:
         ma1      ma2     ma3  intercept
      0.4039  -0.0836  0.5125     0.2752
s.e.  0.1158   0.0905  0.1039     0.6078

sigma^2 estimated as 11.2:  log likelihood = -264.67,  aic = 539.34
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I thought that auto.arima selected the best model based on the AIC.

Comment: Rob's answer shows that this is a statistical issue, specifically relating to the invertibility of the MA(3) model. I vote to keep open.

Answer (score 6):

By default, `auto.arima` uses a stepwise search and there is no guarantee that it will find the best model. You can do a more complete search by setting `stepwise=FALSE` in the call. Like this:

```
> library(forecast)
> auto.arima(ma3,stepwise=FALSE)

Series: ma3 
ARIMA(3,0,0) with zero mean     

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ar3
      0.3203  -0.0556  0.2816
s.e.  0.0976   0.1025  0.0984

sigma^2 estimated as 13.74:  log likelihood=-271.57
AIC=551.15   AICc=551.57   BIC=561.57
```

However, this still hasn't found an MA(3) model. That is because the fitted MA(3) model is almost non-invertible.

```
> fit <- Arima(ma3, order=c(0,0,3))
> plot(fit)
```

[image]

Note the root lies almost on the unit circle. `auto.arima` will not consider models that are close to the stationarity or invertibility boundary, as they are typically numerically unstable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That helps a lot. Also, thanks for the package and the book. I'm new to this area, and the resources you've created are very helpful.

Comment: Does setting `stepwise=FALSE` make `auto.arima` consider **all** submodels until the maximum orders? I.e. if we consider only ARMA($p,q$) (forget SAR, SMA for simplicity), setting `stepwise=FALSE` will mean a full search over the $2^{p+q}$ model space? The help file of `auto.arima` is not explicit on that.

Comment: Yes. Fully explained in the JSS article.

Comment: Article?  Book?  huh?

Comment: Article: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i03. Book: http://otexts.org/fpp